# What is the best database modeling right for this case?

Tags: sql, database

What is the right data modeling for this case?

In my case, an application has multiple editions and each edition has multiple plans. So from that, each customer has a contract to use an application.

**Base Tables:**

```
customers
------------------------------
id              int     PK INC
name            string


applications
------------------------------
id              int     PK INC
name            string
```

First option:
**OPTION #1:**

```
editions
------------------------------
application_id  int     PK FK
id              string  PK      (e.g: "STANDARD", "ADVANCED", "PROFESSIONAL")


plans
------------------------------
application_id  int     PK FK
edition_id      string  PK FK
id              string  PK      (ex: "MONTHLY", "YEARLY")


contracts
------------------------------
customer_id     int     FK
application_id  int     FK
edition_id      string  FK
plan_id         string  FK
id              int     PK INC
```

second option:
 **OPTION #2:**

```
editions
------------------------------
application_id  int     PK FK
id              int     PK
name            string          (ex: "STANDARD", "ADVANCED", "PROFESSIONAL")


plans
------------------------------
application_id  int     PK FK
edition_id      int     PK FK
id              int     PK
name            string  PK      (ex: "MONTHLY", "YEARLY")


contracts
------------------------------
customer_id     int     FK
application_id  int     FK
edition_id      int     FK
plan_id         int     FK
id              int     PK INC
```

third option:
**OPTION #3:**

```
editions
------------------------------
application_id  int     FK
id              int     PK INC
name            string          (ex: "STANDARD", "ADVANCED", "PROFESSIONAL")


plans
------------------------------
edition_id      string  FK
id              int     PK INC
name            string          (ex: "MONTHLY", "YEARLY")


contracts
------------------------------
customer_id     int     FK
plan_id         int     FK
id              int     PK INC
```

**OR ANOTHER?**

```
?
```

Another method to do this?

Comment: I would say that none of those are "best". They all have some strange limitations in the architecture. You have redundant data in both 1 and 2. And 3 is limited to a single contract per edition.

Comment: But....3 is the closest I think. Of course this is likely going to be closed as being too opinion based.

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com). But even then, "best" means little without a good (really, complete) understanding of your actual model and how you intend to use it.

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back if you want, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Questions like this do NOT belong in dba. Its a database design question, not an administration question.

Comment: Unless you have only certain allowable combinations between application, edition and plan, then I would keep them separate, and have a reference to ApplicationID, EditionID and PlanID in the Contract table. If the allowable combinations are limited, then you need a table that contains the allowable combinations, and use a reference to that in your contracts table instead.